# linking a node in networkD3 to a website using clickAction in shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, networkd3

Is there a way to use a node as a link to an external website using the function forceNetwork() in the networkD3 package in r but incorporated into shiny app?

I've found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895960/linking-a-node-in-networkd3-to-a-website-using-clickaction-null)

but it's not working when I am trying to run it as an shiny app.
Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

source =c(0,0,3,3,3,7,7,10,9,7,1,6,4,5,8,2)
target = c(1,2,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,10,9,10,8,9,11,8)
value = c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,20,20,10,2,2,2,10,20,15)
MisLinks = data.frame(source,target,value)


name = c("[Category]Genre", "CCG", "Action",  [Category]Art","Realistic Art", "Dark Art", "Cartoony", "[Category]Time  demend", "Mid-Core", "Hard-Core", "Casual", "Install", "Not Install")
group = c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,8,8)
size = c(50,20,20,50,20,20,20,50,20,20,20,250,250)
hyperlink = c("http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://yahoo.com")
MisNodes = data.frame(name, group, size, hyperlink)



ui = fluidPage(
titlePanel("Testing app"),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("opacity", "Test", 0.6, min = 0.1, max = 1, step = .1)
),
mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Force Network", forceNetworkOutput("force"))
  )
)
)
)

Myclickaction = "window.open(d.name, '_blank')"

server = function(input,output) {

output$force = renderForceNetwork({
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
             Source = "source", Target = "target", charge = -150, 
             legend = TRUE, opacityNoHover = 1, Nodesize = "size",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", linkWidth = 2, clickAction =  Myclickaction,
             opacity = 0.9, colourScale =JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);"),
             zoom=t)


})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Desired outcome: When you click on a node, in a published shiny app
you get a new window open in browser to the specific web page depending on the node clicked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you're missing a quote before `[Category]Art` on line 10
2. you're passing `zoom=t` instead of `zoom=T` on line 44
3. this `Myclickaction = "window.open(d.name, '_blank')"` should be `Myclickaction = "window.open(d.hyperlink, '_blank')"` on line 33
4. on line 38, save the output of `forceNetwork` to an object so that you can modify it later, like `fn <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,`
5. after the `forceNetwork` call (line 45), add `fn$x$nodes$hyperlink <- hyperlink` and then on the next line add `fn`

The problem is that the hyperlinks need to be added after the `forceNetwork` function is run because this trick is not officially supported and the hyperlinks in your node object will be dropped by the `forceNetwork` function.

So the full code with the stated changes plus some formatting fixes looks like...

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

source =c(0,0,3,3,3,7,7,10,9,7,1,6,4,5,8,2)
target = c(1,2,4,5,6,8,9,11,12,10,9,10,8,9,11,8)
value = c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,20,20,10,2,2,2,10,20,15)
MisLinks = data.frame(source,target,value)

name = c("[Category]Genre", "CCG", "Action",  "[Category]Art","Realistic Art", "Dark Art", "Cartoony", "[Category]Time  demend", "Mid-Core", "Hard-Core", "Casual", "Install", "Not Install")
group = c(1,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,6,6,6,8,8)
size = c(50,20,20,50,20,20,20,50,20,20,20,250,250)
hyperlink = c("http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://yahoo.com", "http://yahoo.com")
MisNodes = data.frame(name, group, size, hyperlink)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Testing app"),
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("opacity", "Test", 0.6, min = 0.1, max = 1, step = .1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Force Network", forceNetworkOutput("force"))
      )
    )
  )
)

Myclickaction = "window.open(d.hyperlink, '_blank')"

server = function(input,output) {
  output$force = renderForceNetwork({
    fn <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
      Source = "source", Target = "target", charge = -150,
      legend = TRUE, opacityNoHover = 1, Nodesize = "size",
      Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
      Group = "group", linkWidth = 2, clickAction =  Myclickaction,
      opacity = 0.9, colourScale =JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);"),
      zoom=TRUE)
    fn$x$nodes$hyperlink <- hyperlink
    fn
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Also, you will have to open the shiny app in a browser, because opening the links in a separate RStudio viewer window doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hey man! Thank you so much this fixed the problem. I've made all of the syntax error while trying to format it for stackoverflow, and i wrote this line:
    Myclickaction = "window.open(d.name, '_blank')"
to see if it can pass known variables like name, and that worked, so i guessed it was because forcenetwork doesn't recognize other variables by default, but damn man you saved me, thanks again!

Comment: Using this method, can we add different shapes ( rectangle, triangle, square) to nodes instead of the default circles that we have.