# changing background image within forceNetwork

Tags: r, networkd3

Changing the background color of a networkD3 can be achieved by hijacking some arguments  of the forceNetwork function as @Jota demonstrated here : [Change background color of networkD3 plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133746/change-background-color-of-networkd3-plot).

How would this be extrapolated to changing the background image ?

I have tried few ways without success one of them as follows :

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmltools)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

browsable(
  tagList(
         forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
             Source = "source", Target = "target",
             Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8),
      tags$script('document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(paper.gif)"')
    )
   )
```

Is there a way to alter the background-image in a similar manner as follows :
 linkDistance = JS('function(){d3.select("body").style("background-color", "#910e33"); return 50;}'))  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to fully specify the URL. For instance, this seems to work...

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmltools)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

browsable(
  tagList(
    forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
                 Source = "source", Target = "target",
                 Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                 Group = "group", opacity = 0.8),
    tags$script('document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(https://media.giphy.com/media/dgrEGTo4uk22Y/giphy.gif)"')
  )
)
```

this is another way to do it without using `htmltools`...

```
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

linkJS <- JS('
  function(){
    d3.select("body")
      .style("background-image", "url(https://media.giphy.com/media/dgrEGTo4uk22Y/giphy.gif)")
      .style("background-repeat", "no-repeat")
      .style("background-position", "right bottom");
    return 50;
  }')

forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source", 
             Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8, linkDistance = linkJS)
```

Comment: Any way one can use the arguments like click Action or LinkDistance like this: linkDistance = JS('function(){d3.select("body").style("background-color", "#910e33"); return 50;}')) ?

Comment: Probably, if you specify the full path to the image. Have you tried it?

Comment: does this only work with url or it can also work with locally saved files ?

Comment: Please disregard above comment: the code below works

linkJS <- JS('function(){d3.select("body").style("background-image", "url(file:///C:/Users/John/Desktop/john.jpg)"); return 50;}'),

Comment: Yup, as long as you use the full (and valid) path, as you’ve already figured out. :-)

Comment: any idea how to align the image ? for example at the right bottom corner and without repeat.

Comment: Open a new question... StackOverflow discourages long comment threads, especially when they deviate from the original question

Comment: edited the non-htmltools code above to not repeat the background image and move it to the bottom right corner