# R: add title to networkD3 plot and save

Tags: r, d3.js, htmlwidgets, networkd3, htmltools

I am interested in adding a title to a forceNetwork graph created with [NetworkD3](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/networkD3/index.html) and exporting the html with magrittr.

A solution was found in the [R: HTML Tag Object help page](https://jangorecki.gitlab.io/data.table/library/htmltools/html/tag.html) in order to add a title. Then I was directed to adding htmltool `browsable()` parameters in the ["Change background color of networkD3 plot"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133746/change-background-color-of-networkd3-plot) StackOverflow question - answer from @timelyportfolio.

Below I have provided a minimal working example for adding the title, then saving the network without the title, and finally my non-working attempt to combine the two.

```
library(networkD3)
library(htmltools)

# Load data
data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

# Plot with title in R Viewer
browsable(
  tagList(
    tags$h1("Title"),
      forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
                   Source = "source", Target = "target",
                   Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
  )
)
```

While I can save the without the title using magrittr `%>%`:

```
library(magrittr)

# Plot and save to Mis.html
forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
                 Source = "source", Target = "target",
                 Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                 Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)%>%  
      saveNetwork(file = 'Mis.html')
```

I am having trouble combining the two without getting the following error.

```
#Plot with title and save to title_Mis.html
browsable(
  tagList(
    tags$h1("Title"),
      forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
                   Source = "source", Target = "target",
                   Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   Group = "group", opacity = 0.8)
  )
)%>%  
  saveNetwork(file = 'title_Mis.html')
```

> Error in system.file(config, package = package) :
>       'package' must be of length 1

Apologies, if this is just a simple debug, but I am not a programmer.

Comment: I haven't played around with the ```networkD3``` too extensively, but it feels like a similar problem is documented [here](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/35), where it says "```htmlwidgets::saveWidget``` is designed to save a single ```htmlwidget```, so fails with ```mapSync``` since it is composed of more than one ```htmlwidget```." The object created by ```browsable``` has two. In RStudio you can directly click the export option to html, which works... but yeah, I wouldn't be too happy with this solution either. Let me work around a bit more to see anything else works...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `htmltools::tagList()` function does not return an `htmlwidget` as the `forceNetwork()` function does, so it does not output valid input for the `networkD3::saveNetwork()` function. Try using `htmlwidgets::prependContent()` to add the title like this...

```
library(networkD3)
library(magrittr)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(htmltools)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source", 
             Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
             Group = "group", opacity = 0.8) %>% 
  htmlwidgets::prependContent(htmltools::tags$h1("Title")) %>% 
  saveNetwork(file = 'title_Mis.html')
```